# Execute gexec in a psql command

Tags: postgresql, psql, gexec

I'm trying to pass the `-c` option of [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) a query using `\gexec` but it's not working as I would like:

```sql
psql -d postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/postgres -c "SELECT format( 'ALTER TABLE %I.%I ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);', table_schema, table_name ) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE' \gexec"
```

```sql
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: ...able_schema = 'my_schema' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE' \gexec
```

Is there anything I can do to fix that / or achieve the desired output in another way, or is it simply impossible to run such command using `psql`?

I tried to write `\\gexec` (thinking the backslash was the issue) instead but it's not working either.

I encountered this problem both on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04 servers.

Answer (score 2):

> General options:
>
> -c, --command=COMMAND    run only **single command** (SQL or internal) and exit

Since the command you're trying to run doesn't begin with a backslash, it's considered to be an SQL command and is sent to the server, which obviously balks at `\gexec`.

You can use a here-doc or here-string to send multiple commands, e.g.

```shell
psql -d postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/postgres <<<"SELECT format( 'ALTER TABLE %I.%I ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);', table_schema, table_name ) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE' \gexec"
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to achieve the same on a Windows 10 server?

Comment: Use `echo`, perhaps?